# how to call Stored Proc in EF core and Asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a basic stored proc SearchMovies

`alter PROCEDURE SearchMovies

    @CategoryIds     varchar(50) = null
AS  ...`

I make some calls from data layer:

```
    var categoryIds = new SqlParameter("CategoryIds", "6");

     var aaa = entities.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.SearchMovies @CategoryIds", categoryIds ); => empty values

     var bbb= entities.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.SearchMovies @CategoryIds={0}", categoryIds ); => error: Must declare the scalar variable "@p0".

     var ccc= entities.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.SearchMovies @CategoryIds={0}", "6");  => works
```

so how come the first 2 calls not working, I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Thanks all.

UPDATED:

looks like I messed up things.

```
 var categoryIds = new SqlParameter("@CategoryIds", "6");
entities.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.SearchMovies @CategoryIds", categoryIds )
```

works fine.

Thanks all for help.

Comment: Change the second query to this : `entities.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.SearchMovies @CategoryIds", categoryIds );` and give it a try. No need to have placeholder in this case.

Comment: @Siva Gopal yes I already tried it on the first call => empty results

Comment: What does `not working` mean? First, the parameter name is wrong. SQL Server parameters always have a `@` prefix. Do you get an error, no results?

Comment: Just go through under link . you may get your answer.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170018/Execute-Stored-Procedure-using-Entity-Framework-Co

Answer (score 1):

The name of the parameter is `@CategoryIds` and not `CategoryIds` so change your first line to this:

```
var categoryIds = new SqlParameter("@CategoryIds", 6);
```

Comment: entities.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.SearchMovies @CategoryIds", categoryIds ); with new SqlParameter("@CategoryIds", 6)=> still show empty, and the other 2 show error just like above. How strange.

Comment: @namvo explain the problem in the question itself, not the comments. Post the *actual* error. Syntax errors will result in exceptions anyway. 'Show empty` isn't a problem description, or a problem at all. Why should the query return something if there is no matchig row? What does the stored procedure do anyway?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to convert the value to string, since your procedure requires VARCHAR?

```
var categoryIds = new SqlParameter("CategoryIds", Convert.ToString(6));
```

Comment: Furthermore, `Convert.Tostring` is nothing more than a call to `whateverType.ToString()`.